# Order with frequency table

Tags: r

This is my two matrix , the first is the name of the color and his reaction time, and the second is the name of color, composition and the number of experiment.

```
DF1 <- read.table(text = "   color     time      
                               A        14         
                               B        5         
                               C        15         ", header = TRUE)




DF2 <- read.table(text = "   color     comp     exp
                               A        c0        12
                               B        c3        12
                               C        c4        1
                               A        c7        13", header = TRUE)


datas <- merge(x=DF1, y=DF2, by.x='color', by.y='color')
        datas  <- datas [order(datas$time),]


table(datas$comp,datas$color)
```

I want to have a table of frequency of color but sorted by their respective reaction time (ascendent), what I obtain is

```
     A B C
  c0 1 0 0
  c3 0 1 0
  c4 0 0 1
  c7 1 0 0
```

and i'm looking for :

```
     B A C
  c0 0 1 0
  c3 1 0 0
  c4 0 0 1
  c7 0 1 0
```

how to do this ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table(datas$comp,datas$color)[, DF1$color[order(DF1$time)]]
#     B A C
#  c0 0 1 0
#  c3 1 0 0
#  c4 0 0 1
#  c7 0 1 0
```